# Silverlight DataGrid: Set visibility of control within row details template?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have an instance where the details template has two main stack panels within it.

One is set to collapsed by default. However upon right click and choosing, that stack panel's visibility is to be triggered. This may occur when the row details are expanded already.

However when the row details are expanded and the right click is chosen to view that stack panel, I'm programmatically changing its visibility to Visible but it's not becoming visible.

Is there a secondary call I need to make to update the UI and force the visibility setting to take?

Here's my code:

```
        private void SetWFHistoryVisibility(bool show)
    {
        var elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(position, this);
        var row = (from element in elements
                   where element is DataGridRow
                   select element).FirstOrDefault() as DataGridRow;

        if (row != null)
        {
            DataGridDetailsPresenter presenter = VisualHelper.FindVisualChild<DataGridDetailsPresenter>(row);
            if (presenter.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                var grid = (from el in presenter.Children
                            where el is Grid
                            select el).FirstOrDefault() as Grid;

                if (grid != null)
                {
                    StackPanel wfgc = grid.FindName("wfGridContainer") as StackPanel;
                    if (show)
                        wfc.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    else
                        wfc.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the XAML of your details template?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call DataGridView.Refresh(), or equivalent depending on your panel/layout.  Also it can be a parent control as well needing to update/refresh.

I know that in Silverlight DataGrid does have an [AutoRefresh](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/automatic-datagrid-refresh-in-silverlight/), but it is primarily controlled by an EventTrigger either in a DGV or DataGrid class.  As you discovered it isn't perfect.

Perhaps you can trigger one of the following events and allow the Control to work out it's own view update.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

This one solution:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
//set the added control to be visible
});
```

Was suggested by a user on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/82e2e076-10c8-443b-aeb1-8fb20a4606ee/stack-panel-inside-accordion-pane-not-refreshing) for StackPanel refreshing.

Several other suggestions suggest utilizing a combination of:

```
_.Invalidate()
_.UpdateLayout()
```

For forcing a refresh.

Comment: I appreciate it, i gave both a shot and neither worked. i wrapped the "if(show)" conditional in the dispatcher call and it didn't take until i collapsed/expanded the row again.
i also added the invalidate and updatelayout calls post visibility change and that didn't affect it either until i collapsed/expanded.